# "Deploy aborted" while running `update_depot_tools`

Tags: ubuntu, v8, depottools

I'm trying to fetch/build v8 and need to install depot_tools first. While running `update_depot_tools`, I keep getting errors starting with the error

```
[P59642 22:11:48.064 deployer.go:355 W] [unzip  1/12] Deploy aborted, cleaning up /home/vagrant/<path>/depot_tools/.cipd_bin/.cipd/pkgs/0/Hz9uNZz5u8kQl3EeiK9dDXUNuFSGNvUCIKeDFSxkf4QC
```

And cannot for the life of me figure out why/cannot find the source to debug the underlying go code.

Answer (score 0):

It worked once I cloned depot_tools directly into my home directory! I hate computers sometimes.

Hope this saves someone a couple of hours that I wasted.

Comment: If you follow the official instructions (https://v8.dev/docs/source-code), it also works out of the box. I've just done that on a freshly installed machine last week. Maybe you forgot to update your `PATH` or something? depot_tools definitely don't care where exactly they're checked out.

Comment: I definitely updated my `PATH`. I'm not sure what to tell you but this solved the issue for me.